# woocommerce cart-view page broken after clicking in edit with elemtor

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, elementor, gutenberg-blocks

I am working in Wordpress on a website and I am using Woocommerce.
Good to know, I had disabled the Gutenberg editor and I am working in the classic editor.
I have a question regarding the woocommerce cart-view page.
Till I came to the point of styling my view-cart page, I had not touched the view-cart page and when visiting that page, it worked fine.
However somehow I have clicked in the page edit in edit with elementor, and since
the view page is showing, the blocks code.

I have enabled Gutenberg again, this didn't solve it, and I am curious about clicking back on the  edit with wordpress editor button, as this might break the site even more.

How can I get the view cart page back to normal view?

```
Cart
wp:woocommerce/cart-items-block
wp:woocommerce/cart-line-items-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-line-items-block wp:woocommerce/cart-cross-sells-block
wp:heading {"fontSize":"large"}
You may be interested in…
/wp:heading wp:woocommerce/cart-cross-sells-products-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-cross-sells-products-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-cross-sells-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-items-block wp:woocommerce/cart-totals-block
wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-block
wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-heading-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-heading-block wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-coupon-form-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-coupon-form-block wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-subtotal-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-subtotal-block wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-fee-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-fee-block wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-discount-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-discount-block wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-shipping-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-shipping-block wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-taxes-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-taxes-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-block wp:woocommerce/cart-express-payment-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-express-payment-block wp:woocommerce/proceed-to-checkout-block
/wp:woocommerce/proceed-to-checkout-block wp:woocommerce/cart-accepted-payment-methods-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-accepted-payment-methods-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-totals-block
wp:heading {"textAlign":"center","className":"with-empty-cart-icon wc-block-cart__empty-cart__title"}
Your cart is currently empty!
/wp:heading wp:separator {"className":"is-style-dots"}
/wp:separator wp:heading {"textAlign":"center"}
New in store
/wp:heading wp:woocommerce/product-new {"columns":4,"rows":1} /
```